# Why doesn't my priority_queue which contains my class objects in C++ work correctly?

Tags: c++, priority-queue

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

class Member
{
public:
    int ID;
    int age;
    Member() {

        ID = 0;
        age = 0;
    }
    Member(int i, int a) {
        ID = i;
        age = a;
    }
    bool operator<(const Member& t2)
    {
        if (age < t2.age) return true;
        else if (age == t2.age && ID > t2.ID) return true;
        return false;
    }
};
int main() {
    priority_queue<Member*> pq;
    Member* member1 = new Member(2,1); // I must contain pointer.
    Member* member2 = new Member(1,2);
    Member* member3 = new Member(3,6);
    Member* member4 = new Member(4,4);
    Member* member5 = new Member(5,4);
    pq.push(member1);
    pq.push(member2);
    pq.push(member3);
    pq.push(member4);
    pq.push(member5);
    while (!pq.empty()) {
        cout << pq.top()->ID << "  " <<  pq.top()->age << endl;
        pq.pop();
    }

}
```

ID : primary key, uniqueness.
I want to include members by age. If the age is the same, the ID is placed in the order of the smallest.

But my code shows strange answer..
Did I inadvertently define the operator function?
what reason??

Comment: You have a queue of `Member*` but your operator compares `Member&`.

Comment: And your comparison operator overload is broken. Comparison operators should take `const` references.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, @-Ry- I revise with your feedback. but It not works..

Comment: Still wrong. Your operator should be of the form `bool operator <(const Member&)`, with another possible `const` at the end.

Comment: Is there any reason for using dynamically allocated `Member`s? This is causing you a great deal of trouble.

Comment: @user4581301 
Later I will change my age. I want the queues to sort automatically when age changes.

Comment: You're in for a nasty surprise then. Ask yourself "How the queue is supposed to know I changed a member variable of an object inside the queue?"

Comment: @user4581301 So.. what should I do? I'm a beginner and I'm not sure.

Comment: What you should do is continue reading your C++ book, and learn the language; specifically aiming to understand what pointers are, and how they work. Your fondness of `new` strongly suggests that you come from a Java background. If so, the best thing to do is to forget everything about Java. C++ is not Java. Very similar syntax, but C++ objects work fundamentally different from Java. If one keeps trying to use C++ like Java, they'll be in a world of pain.